# .NET библиотеки для работы с видео\аудио

Tags: c#, .net, видео, аудио

Доброго времени суток всем!
Ищу библиотеки для вытягивания тэгов из аудио и видео (исполнитель, группа, время и тп.).
Поддержка основных форматов (mp3, wma, wav, ogg, mp4, avi, mov, flv etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Однозначно [Bass Audio](http://www.un4seen.com/) для аудио и [VideoLab](http://www.mitov.com/html/products.html) для видео.